# How to resize Collection View cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to auto-resize the cell of a collection view. In the iPhone 8 the design is okay, but when I try it on other devices, especially with the iPhone SE, the cell is not autoresizing and often the cell is too big or too small. I'm working with:

[image]

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you are trying to do is this

> No matter the screen size, I always want 2 (or say n) items a row !

Then you need `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

You can try the following piece of code

```
  let itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 - 3

  let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
  layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemSize, height: itemSize)

  layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
  layout.minimumLineSpacing = 3

  collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

In the above code , replace **2** on line:

> let itemSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/**2** - 3

with the number of items you want **in a single row**

You can place this code in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewDidAppear()`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to the mismatch between your

1. EdgeInset
2. Cell Spacing
3. Width of your Cell

Solution:-

Add the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate and add these methods and update your values according to your requirement like :-

```
let edge    : CGFloat = 10.0
let spacing : CGFloat = 10.0

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: edge, bottom: 0, right: edge)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spacing
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let noOfColumn = 2
    let collectionviewWidth = collectionView.frame.width
    let bothEdge =  CGFloat(edge + edge) // left + right
    let excludingEdge = collectionviewWidth - bothEdge
    let cellWidthExcludingSpaces = excludingEdge - ((noOfColumn-1) * spacing)
    let finalCellWidth = cellWidthExcludingSpaces / noOfColumn
    let height = finalCellWidth
    return CGSize(width: finalCellWidth, height: height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

     return CGSize(width: value, height: value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this  it will work:

First you have to Add the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate and then use following delegate method it will work fine for me.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let padding: CGFloat =  10
        let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize/2)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 10 / Swift 4**

Implement the below method,, it is autoresized base on the screen you have.

```
  // Collection View Layout
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

            let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            return CGSize.init(width: (screenWidth-55) / 2, height: (screenWidth-55) / 2 * 1.481)

        }
```